# programmatically setting up eucalyptus node controller keys

Tags: ssh, openssh, eucalyptus

I had a general question regarding the way eucalyptus setups ssh keypairs for the various controllers like cluster, node etc.
Currently my task at hand is to automate setup of eucalyptus (including ssh'ing into machines and settuping up cluster controller and node controllers).
If i have to do this programmatically, i need somehow setup sshkeys for node controllers. How do i go about doing that.
After registering a nc by hand, i don't see any authorized_keys file in either root's home or eucalyptus's home. 
Also the /etc/ssh/sshd_config does not show a change in authorized_keys location on the node-controller.

Please help me resolve this question.

Answer (score 1):

Eucalyptus ssh connection between the CC and the NCs is done using the *eucalyptus* user.  The root directory for the user *eucalyptus* is */var/lib/eucalyptus*.  There you'll find the *.ssh* directory containing the **knownhost** and the **id_rsa.pub** files.

In the Eucalyptus [install/configuration process](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/PackageInstall) you'll find more info.